# Qt5 QListView set up items in a horizontal row instead of vertical list

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

I am setting up a `QListView` with a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` and I would like to have my items rendered so they are in a horizontal 'row'.

Assuming our `QListView` has models that are "A", "B", and "C", the standard view will have them as:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|X[ A                                                                          ]X|
| [ B                                                                          ] |
| [ C                                                                          ] |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

with each item taking up the entire width. What I want to do is have `A` `B` and `C` in a horizontal orientation even though the model has each one in a separate row (and only one column throughout the view).

`X[ A ]X  [ B ]  [ C ]`

(`X` == selected item background)

The reason I cannot use a `QTableView` is because I will have the items increase and decrease in size, therefore require wrapping when they get too wide to fit on one line; constantly changing the columns, rows, and cell sizes in a table seems like more work than is necessary for this to work, plus I don't want table borders in the view.

So far I've tried overriding `sizeHint` and `paint` methods. I don't think I need editor methods because these items won't have an edit mode to go into.

Any basic example would be sufficient for me. If you write your answer in PyQt5 and it helps me to find my answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer even though I'm using C++.

Comment: I had also misconfigured some of my delegate code, so that is my fault. However, @ariaman5 answered my main concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the flow property from "TopToBottom" to "LeftToRight" with setFlow as below:

```
listView->setFlow(QListView::Flow::LeftToRight);
```